# Select objects from django model based on user input

Tags: python, html, jquery, django, django-models

I have a large django model with about 800 objects and I want to create a view in which the user can select a certain number of those objects to pass to another view for further processing. The fact that there are so many objects of the model makes listing all the objects very unpractical, as the user would have to scroll through 800 objects.

In order to address this problem, I want to place an as-you-type search-bar in the top of the view so that the user can type the name of the objects and select them by clicking them. When the objects are selected, they should appear under the search-bar as tags that the user can remove by clicking an "x" next to each one.

When the user has made all the required selections, then they should be able to click a button and jump to the next view where those selected objects are accessible.

The model I am using can be simplified to:

```
class Song():
    song_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    song_author = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    song_content = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_name
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['song_order']

    song_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, db_index=True)
```

So far I have been able to make a view to search through the model.

**mytemplate.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html style="height: 100%;" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
    <link rel="preload" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


{% block body_block %}
    <div class="container" style="padding-bottom:40px;margin-top: 35px;">   
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="searchInput" class="bmd-label-floating">Search</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchInput" oninput="filter()">
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group bmd-list-group-sm">
            {% for song in songs %}
                <div
                    class="list-group-item"
                    data-title="{{song.song_name}}"
                    data-author="{{song.song_author}}"
                    data-lyrics="{{song.song_content}}">
                <h4>
                    {{song.song_name}}
                    {% if song.song_author %}
                        ({{ song.song_author }})
                    {% endif %}
                </h4>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>

    $('#searchInput').focus();

    function short(s) {
        let punctuationRegEx = /[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g;
        return s.replace(punctuationRegEx, '')
                .toLowerCase()
                .normalize("NFD")
                .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
    }

    function filter() {
        let f = short($('#searchInput').val());
        $('.list-group-item').each(function (index) {
            if (short($(this).data('title') + "").includes(f) ||
                short($(this).data('author') + "").includes(f)
            ) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }
    </script>

{% endblock %}


</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
class SongListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'songs'
    model = Song
    template_name = "songapp/mytemplate.html"
```

Any ideas on how to do the selection?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a part inventory program with the as you type search.
It's a complete example of ajax call for search and database.
You can modify it to show the results under the search with the X.

https://github.com/edcodes/Django-Parts-Inventory

Comment: Thanks, but that part is just what I have already implemented. The part I am more interested in is the one about selecting the results and making them appear as tags under the search bar. If you have any suggestions, please let me know!